# Removing the uninstall option from app shortcuts in Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I am working on my app with new Oreo app shortcut features. For me on long press the app shortcuts are showing, but in some device like onePlus on long press it shows appInfo and uninstall options also, which i am not adding in my shortcuts. These options are not showing in device like Nexus5s with Oreo. Is there any way i can disable there options since it is available in some device and not available in others?
Thanks for your help in advance..

Comment: it depends on device company which can facilitate with this or not and you can't customize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way. These additional options are added by launcher, not your app itself. Obviously, uninstall options will be not there if your app is not possible to be uninstalled (it's system app for example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is there any way to hide these options if available?.

Comment: No, there is no way.